# tengo poner checkbox en mi formulario que tiene un campo ManyToManyFields en el modelo

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Estoy tradando de mostrar el campo **category** en el formulario que en el modelo es un campo **ManyToManyFields** y actualizar los datos que tengo, he intentado con **CheckboxSelectMultiple** pero no muestra los datos, solo un listado pero sin datos ni campos de checkbox

en mi plantilla llamo al formualrio como un **{{form}}** para mostrar todos los **fields**

**forms.py**

```py
class PostUpdateForms(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CreatePost
        fields = ['title', 'img', 'category', 'content' ]
        widgets = {
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            
        }
```

**models.py**

```py
class Categories(models.Model):

    category = models.CharField(verbose_name="Categoria", max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Categoria'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categorias'
        ordering = ['category']
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category


def custom_upload_to(instance, filename):

    #old_intance = CreatePost.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    #old_intance.img.delete()
    return 'post/'+filename

class CreatePost(models.Model):

    #user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Usuario")
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Titulo", max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Contenido", null=True, blank=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=custom_upload_to, null=True, blank=False)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Categories)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(CreatePost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Anime'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Animes'
        ordering = ['-created']
```

si uso esto en el Meta widgets, me muestra un listado y no los checkbox

**'category':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()**

[image: si uso category':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la solución seria esta:

```
class PostUpdateForms(forms.ModelForm):

    # Indicar el queryset de las categorias
    category = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Categories.objects.all(),
                                                    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    class Meta:
        model = CreatePost
        fields = ['title', 'img', 'category', 'content' ]
        widgets = {
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            
        }
```

Me comentas si te funciono, saludos.